# Memory consumption of each accept() call on server running on Windows 2008

Tags: windows, memory, sockets

I've written a simple and small server application on Windows 2008 that just accepts connections and does nothing else. I am doing memory footprint assessment of socket calls, What I found that each connection (after accept()) consumes at least 2.5 KB of memory. Interestingly, the memory is not consumed by the process that has accept() call but it consumed by a OS process. I believe it might be because of data structures being created inside OS for each connection.

Now, I have two key questions:

Is it possible by any means to reduce this memory footprint (by changing any parameters, configuration etc) ? If yes how ? (Because 2K for each connection would be too much if we planning server to accept millions of connections)

If my server is intended to accept million connections, is it good idea to use Windows 2008 ? or shall I switch to some other OS?

Please advice me.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask on [SO] ?

Comment: @Atul PLEASE don't cross-post. Ask your question on the most appropriate site and await an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Millions of TCP connections?  Simultaneously on one box?  If you achieve that, please publish your findings. There are folks at Microsoft, Amazon, Facebook, and Google that would love to know how you got 1M simultaneous connections on a single box. Seriously, if your service is that large, wouldn't you plan for a modest 10-100K connections per box and use a load balancer across multiple servers?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the 2.5K is in the socket buffers.  You can reduce the size with setsockopt SO_RECVBUF and SO_SNDBUF calls.  There will be other memory used but setting these should reduce the memory footprint.

This is how http servers and the like can scale to many thousands concurrent connections at a time.  Without that the memory could run out pretty fast.

Have a look at this link for more info:
[How to retain one million simultaneous TCP connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831434/how-to-retain-one-million-simultaneous-tcp-connections)

I should point out that your question should really be on stackoverflow.com

Comment: It won't work. The implementation has to lock the send and receive buffers in memory and cannot lock amounts less than a page. The only way to do this is to manage the buffers entirely in your own application, setting the kernel buffer sizes to zero. (This is tricky stuff to get right, but Windows lets you do it.)

Answer (score 0):

1. No. The connection structure must be created and tracked by the kernel so that received packets can be processed correctly. Things like the window size, path MTU, and all kinds of other things need to be stored. You'll eventually need receive buffers and so on.
2. It's hard to say without knowing a lot more about your specific application (what are all these connections actually doing). But doing 200,000 current connections is extremely difficult and requires someone very familiar with that specific problem domain.

Comment: Hi David, many thanks for quick reply.

1. If I am planning to send/receive very short length strings (say 16 bytes) cannot I specify it somewhere to reduce memory footprint ?

2. I asked this question because I mostly heard of commercial server application running on Unix/Linux etc but not on Windows. However, I read that Windows 2008 is promising platform in this regard. But not sure if anyone has tried it for millions of connections.

Comment: 1) Yes, but only if you set the kernel buffers to zero and manage all the buffers yourself. You can then make the send/receive buffers take as few pages as possible. 2) With 24GB of RAM, it should be possible. But I don't know anyone who has actually done it.