# How many tcp connections on different ports a sever can handle?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I am designing a server client app in C#.
the client connect and communicate with the sever threw tcp socket.

in the server side I am using the socket.accept() method in order to handle new connection from client. when client is connecting, the server use a random port in order to communicate with the client.

so my question is.. how many clients the server can receive in this kind of form?
is there another form that I should use in order to handle lots of clients?

Comment: so 65k is the max i can handle at the same time?
what you mean about tear down connections?

Comment: @oleksii This is completely incorrect from start to finish. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the server side i am using the socket.accept() method in order to handle new connection from client. when client is connecting, the server use a random port in order to communicate with the client.

Not unless you open another, pointless, connection from server to client, and you won't be doing that for firewall reasons. The accepted socket uses the same local port number as the listening socket. Contrary to several answers and comments here.

Your question is therefore founded on a misconception. Whatever you run out of, and it could be memory, thread handles, socket handles, socket buffer space, CPUs, CPU power, virtual memory, disk space, ..., it won't be TCP ports.

**EDIT** Adherents of the new-random-port theory need to explain the following `netstat` output:

```
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         127.0.0.1:53777        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         127.0.0.1:53793        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         127.0.0.1:53794        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         127.0.0.1:53795        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         127.0.0.1:53796        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         127.0.0.1:53798        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.4:8009         127.0.0.1:53935        ESTABLISHED
```

and show where in [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) it says anything about allocating a new port to an accepted socket, and where in the TCP connect-handshake exchange the new port number is conveyed.

Comment: Ok but why in the socket object it shows me local port:xxxx which is different from the listening port of the socket.accept

Comment: @AviThalker If you're referring to the accepted socket, it doesn't show a different local port at all: what you describe is impossible. Look again. If you're referring to the client-side socket, of course it's a different local port, but that isn't the question you asked. The local port number at the client has no bearing on the capacity of the server.

Answer (score 3):

This is practically limited by the OS. You have to test this. On Windows you must use fully asynchronous socket IO at this scale. You will probably be limited by memory usage.

On a TCP level there is no practical limit. There can be one connection for each combination of `(server port, server ip, client port, client ip)`. So with one server port and one server ip you can serve an unlimited amount of clients as long as they have less than 65k connections per client.

You do not need to pick a random port on the server. This is a common misconception.

Comment: +1 for not getting the accepted port issue wrong like everybody else, but at what scale? The OP hasn't mentioned any particular scale.

Comment: Basically it will come down to how much memory the kernel can allocate for keeping track of connections.

Comment: @EJP you're right. I had assumed he's in a region of scale where you have to think about limits.

Answer (score -1):

You may like to see this question I asked in similar vein: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234672/is-there-are-problem-holding-large-numbers-of-open-socket-connections-for-length, and particularly some of the comments.

The answer seems to be that there is no practical limit. The combination of receive port and send port must be unique, and each of them can have 64K values. The total number of combinations is extremely large. There really are servers out there with extremely large numbers of open connections, but to get there you have to solve a number of other interesting problems. The question above contains a link to an article about a million connection server. See also [How to retain one million simultaneous TCP connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831434/how-to-retain-one-million-simultaneous-tcp-connections). And do a web search for the C10K problem.

What you probably cannot do is use synchronous ports and threads because you run into thread limits, not port limits. You have to use asynchronous ports and a thread pool. And you will have to write one to throw away, just to find out how to do it.

Comment: Certainly he can he use synchronous ports, by which you presumably mean synchronous, blocking sockets, and threads. There are millions of TCP servers out there that do exactly that. However there are certainly not any 'servers out there with extremely large numbers of ports', or 'million port servers'. They all have 65535 TCP ports and 65535 UDP ports. There are however servers that can handle millions of *connections.* -1

Comment: You conflated ports, of which there are 65535, with sockets and connections, of which there are a considerably larger number potentially available. I don't consider saying so to be even slightly 'picky', and I don't consider an edit which corrects the conflation to be even slightly 'minor'. There's a considerable difference between 64k and 'millions'.

Comment: Look at the problems the confusion between ports and connections has caused in other answers here and elsewhere. Electrical engineers don't say volts when they mean amps do they?

Comment: But physicists routinely say weight when they mean mass. I used the wrong word, I corrected it, my answer is now better, so what's the problem? That's how SO is supposed to work.

Comment: The ‘pickiness’ enabled you to improve your answer, slightly. That is also how SO is supposed to work. And now what does your final paragraph mean? What is an ‘asynchronous port’?

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, you can run those commands to find the maximum amount of ports that can be used (which limits maximum amount of connections) :

```
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport udp
netsh int ipv6 show dynamicport tcp
netsh int ipv6 show dynamicport udp
```

It should be 16384 (starting **Windows Vista** and **Windows Server 2008**). Before, it was approximately 4000.

More info : [the default dynamic port range for TCP/IP has changed since Windows Vista and
in Windows Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang) and [troubleshoot port exhaustion issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcp-ip-port-exhaustion-troubleshooting).

This limit can be changed by creating a new  DWORD entry in registry (need computer reboot) : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` > `MaxUserPort`

Please kind in mind that a connection will go into `TIME_WAIT` state after being closed and thus will still use a port for a while (120 seconds by default). This can also limit the number of connections that can be established.